# How to reserve a DIV width with "left:100%" CSS rule

Tags: html, css, css-position, absolute

If placing an absolute position with `left:100%`, the `DIV` will not reserve the normal width depending on its content. Instead, the width will be minimized by breaking the text over spaces.

Here is a simple [EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/hSTY4/)

How is it possible to place an absolute position with `left:100%` (which is located just outside the parent), but keeping the `DIV` content (text) in one line.

Note that the text length and `DIV` width are unknown, as the width must be set according to the inner content.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If all you want is for your absolute div to have his text on one line you can put:

```
white-space:nowrap;
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hSTY4/1/)

Is this what you're after?

Answer (score 2):

You have two options:

In your .test style you can either add a `white-space:nowrap;` or `width:100%;` works too

Comment: The first one is the practical solution. I do not know how I simply forgot about `white-space` :p